# How to use the id of the parent table as a parameter in onclick event?

Tags: javascript, html, html-table

I will have this button once for each table (about `25` distinct tables) on this page and I'm hoping to find a way to have the `onclick` event call the function `constructDataValueString` and pass in the `id` of the parent table (so that I don't have to explicitly reference the table id).

Is there a way to write:

```
onclick="constructDataValueString(*id_of_parent_table*)"
```

**Graphical example of the HTML markup:**

[image: My HTML structure]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [closest()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest), for example:

```
onclick="constructDataValueString(this.closest('table').id)"
```

**Example**

```js
const constructDataValueString = (id) => console.log("table id is: ", id);
```

```css
.as-console {background-color:black !important; color:lime;}
.as-console-wrapper {max-height:50% !important;}
```

```html
<table id="populationbyage" border="2">
<thead>TABLE</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>
      Some Cell...
    </td>
    <td>
      <button onclick="constructDataValueString(this.closest('table').id)">
        Copy
      </button>
    </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: A few seconds ahead with the same example, congrats!

Answer (score 1):

Sure - use `this.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.id`:

```js
function constructDataValueString(id) {
  console.log(id);
}
```

```html
<table id="populationbyage">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <button onclick="constructDataValueString(this.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.id)">Copy</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

(The above is a minimalistic example - it follows the exact same structure, it just has only the necessary elements and attributes required.

Answer (score 1):

To ensure your internal `table` structure can change without affecting this part, you could use `this.closest("table")` so that you get the first parent `<table>` element, from where you can get the id:

`constructDataValueString(this.closest("table").id)`

Answer (score 0):

A more flexible solution

```
function parent(el, selector) {
    var matchesFn;

    // find vendor prefix
    ['matches', 'webkitMatchesSelector', 'mozMatchesSelector', 'msMatchesSelector', 'oMatchesSelector'].some(function (fn) {
        if (typeof document.body[fn] == 'function') {
            matchesFn = fn;
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    });

    var parent;

    // traverse parents
    while (el) {
        parent = el.parentElement;
        if (parent && parent[matchesFn](selector)) {
            return parent;
        }
        el = parent;
    }

    return null;
}

<table id="populationbyage">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <button onclick="console.log(parent(event.target, '#populationbyage'))">Copy</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

As other answers suggest, use closest() 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest

To answer your question and also to address someone who wants a particular element to be sent, there is a way to exactly send the id of the table or any tag which you want.

```
`<table id="populationbyage" border="2">
<thead>TABLE</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>
      Some Cell...
    </td>
    <td>
      <button onclick="constructs(this.closest('#populationbyage').id)">
        Copy
      </button>
    </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<script>
    function constructs(id) {
        console.log(id)     
    }
</script>
`
```

The fetching of the id approach will pinpoint to the table you want to access here. It will help you to ignore all the nested tables if in future you wish to add some.